# Cannot Convert from Method Group to Object - C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get familiar with C# and tried out the following program - it just outputs the average of the even numbers in the Array.

[image: Code Snippet][image: Errors]

Would be great if someone could highlight the problem here.

Comment: It would be way easier if you would post the code as text.  I was going to throw that into Visual Studio, but I'm not going to retype the code.  Tip: StackOverflow can automatically format code for you if you mark a section as code.

Comment: you should refer to the class you are trying to use in `msdn`..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need `select.Average()` (with the parens).

Answer (score 5):

The Missing Parenthesis `()` is the reason for your error.It should be `Average()`

without a Parenthesis,it is understood as a method group.The average method could have multiple overloads and it is unclear which specific overloaded method needs to be invoked.But when you mention the parenthesis it makes the intention clearer and the method gets called.

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `Average`. should be `select.Average()`

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that, you forgot to include the parenthesis since `Average` is a method (*extension type*). Another solution is to use lambda expression, something like this,

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Where(x => (x % 2) == 0).Average());
```

or

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var select = (from num in numbers where (num % 2) == 0 select num).Average();
Console.WriteLine(select);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an Extension **`Method`** so it should be like this: `Average()`

with ( Parenthesis() )

Answer (score 0):

This was a careless mistake on my part, I was trying to call Method like a property instead of Method() like a method