# Passing an eventhandler as a method argument

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to pass an event handler to one of my method. This might look stupid but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I have the red few questions here around on SO but I still don't get over it.

I have the following method signature

```
public void SyncWithInfo(Action<object, EventArgs> cellValueChanged,
    int indexValeurFr, int indexValeurEn, int indexUnite)
```

And where I'm trying to call it using this piece of code

```
private void myMethod()
{
    dgvform.SyncWithInfo(dgvform_CellValueChanged, valeur.Index,
        valeurEN.Index, unite.Index);
}

private void dgvform_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //stuff
}
```

I have the following error :

> cannot convert from 'method group' to `'System.Action<object, System.EventArgs>'`

From what I have red somewhere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13116032/2145522) on SO refering a method directly by its name without any parameter is considered a 'method group' since there could be X overload of that method.

So here is my question : How can I pass my event handler as an argument for my method?

Comment: You have a mismatch between DataGridViewCellEventargs and Event args on the delegate. Normally upcasting would work, but there is likely a variance issue here.

Comment: @LordTakkera Omg it like it was simply that... I cannot belive it was that stupid

Comment: The first compiler error you are getting is `The best overloaded method match for 'the method' has some invalid arguments`, which is accurate. The second one that you mentioned is missleading.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I agree but i still don't understand why it wasn't alright since `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`is an `EventArgs`.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the `SyncWithInfo` signature has to use the explict type for `EventArg`. so that the method signature would look like:

```
public void SyncWithInfo(Action<object, DataGridViewCellEventArgs> cellValueChanged,
    int indexValeurFr, int indexValeurEn, int indexUnite)
```

Comment: This has fixed my compilation error so I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer has the solution, but to try and provide a bit of explanation:

Normally, you can assign derived types to their base types:

```
EventArgs e = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs();
```

However, when you start dealing with generics (which is what your action is, a generic delegate), things get a little weird. You have to start dealing with a concept called variance. By default, generics are not covariant. Covariance means that you are allowed to use a derived type as a type argument. Contravariance means you can go the other way.

Some generics, like IEnumerable, are marked as covariant (by using out T as their type parameter). That's why you can do:

```
IEnumerable<object> = new List<String>();
```

Action delegates are not covariant, and so the sample code will not compile.

Covariance and Contravariance on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for adding more information about the reason it didn't worked. Take my +1

Comment: It has nothing to do with the variance of generic type arguments here. The problem occurs even if the argument is declared with a corresponding non-generic delegate. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation of @LordTakkera is wrong (sorry). It has nothing to do with the variance associated to generics here. You will get the same problem with a plain (non-generic) delegate.

A method can accept values having types that are more derived than the argument type specified in the method header. The method we have to consider here is the event handler that we want to pass as argument to another method. If this event handler expects an argument of type `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` it will not accept an argument of type `EventArgs` which is less derived.

If you could pass this event handler as delegate to an argument of type `Action<object, EventArgs>` of another method, this other method could call our event handler and pass it an `EventArgs` argument; however, the event handler expects a `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` argument.

On the other hand, the opposite situation works.

```
private void AcceptsEventHandler(Action<object, DataGridViewCellEventArgs> handler)
{
    // handler is SomeEventHandler if we call:
    //           AcceptsEventHandler(SomeEventHandler);

    handler(this, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(1, 2));
}

private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // We are getting a DataGridViewCellEventArgs as second argument here, which is ok.
}
```

This works:

```
AcceptsEventHandler(SomeEventHandler);
```

Comment: +1 This make sense... now you pointed it out it's perfectly clear