# How to register singleton on Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, singleton, autofac

I am using `Autofac` for dependency injection in my `.Net Core 2.0` web application. I am new to `Autofac`and dependency injection concepts.

Now, I want to register a singleton in `DI` and resolve it in DI container.

**C# Code [Interface]**

```
public interface IMongoDbContext
    {
        IMongoDatabase Database { get; }
    }
```

**Class**

```
public class MongoDbContext : IMongoDbContext
    {
        public MongoDbContext(string connectionString, string databaseName);

        public string DatabaseName { get; }
        public IMongoDatabase Database { get; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; }
    }
```

**Repository Class**

```
public class DemoRepository : IDemoRepository
{
    public DemoRepository(IMongoDataContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

**Now, in .Autofac**

```
    builder.Register(c => new MongoDbContext(dbConnectionString, dataBaseName)).As<IMongoDbContext>().SingleInstance();
    //dbConnectionString and dataBaseName are string variables declared above.

    // and then to Resolve it 
    builder.Register(c => new DemoRepository(c.Resolve<IMongoDbContext>)).As<IDemoRepository>();
// but in above line it shows error at `c.Resolve<IMongoDbContext>`  it shows `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'IMongoDbContext'`
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this. I am new to autofac and dependency Injection, I want to know how I can register Singleton in autofac.

Any help would be highly appreciated ...!!

Thanks

Comment: `it shows error at c.Resolve<IMongoDbContext>` What is the error?

Comment: @mjwills - it shows `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'IMongoDbContext'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Convert from Method Group to Object - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116004/cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-object-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c.Resolve<IMongoDbContext>
```

should be:

```
c.Resolve<IMongoDbContext>()
```

*You forgot to call / invoke the function.*

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out that why are you injecting manually `IMongoDataContext` when registering `DemoRepository`. Is it not main purpose of Inversion of Control Tool ?  I think, you should change your approach;

```
builder.RegisterType<DemoRepository>().As<IDemoRepository>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might include single instance with register type

```
builder.RegisterType<DemoRepository>().As<IDemoRepository>().SingleInstance();
```